# Can I use mocha to unit test react-templates in my ecmascript-6 app?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, react-templates

I have replaced all my React jsx with [react-templates](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/) in an ecmascript-6 app. I really love having the html templates in a dedicated .rt file instead of mingled in with the es6 code; jsx just seemed wrong.

I'm using webpack-dev-server in development.  I had to convert .rt to es6  in a preLoader step to get this working, then the regular es6-to-commonjs babel loader operates on the result. Webpack is working fine in dev and production.  `webpack -p` compiles and minifies everything down to a commonjs chunk for production builds.  Fine so far.

Here's my functioning module loaders config in webpack.config.js:

```
...
  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.rt$/,
      loader: 'react-templates?modules=es6'
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$|\.rt$/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', ['css', 'sass?sourceMap'])
    }]
  },
...
```

Here's where the trouble starts -- I had mocha unit tests working with jsx components, but I can't seem to get the same unit tests to run now that I'm using react-templates.

Mocha will compile es6 js to commonjs with a special --compiler, but the only thing I can find for react templates and mocha is a module [mocha-react-templates-compiler](https://github.com/talpor/mocha-react-templates-compiler) that is hard-coded to convert the templates directly to commonjs, not es6.

So, lines like this in my es6:

`import MyComponentRT from './MyComponent.rt'`

work great in dev and prod but do *not* work in mocha tests.

I tried:

`mocha --recursive --compilers rt:mocha-react-templates-compiler,js:babel-register ./js/test`

But I get errors that are clearly related to es6 code expecting the rt files to also be es6.  Reversing the compiler order does not help.

Is anyone else using react-templates and es6 and mocha in the same project?  How did you get mocha tests to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with gulp.

I used gulp to explicitly compile .rt files to es6 and then compile the es6 down to .rt.js similar to what webpack is configured to do.  All output files are dumped into a temporary "testbuild" folder, then the same is done for the .js files, and mocha can run the tests from there.

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var rt = require('gulp-react-templates');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

var testbuild_dir = 'testbuild';

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(testbuild_dir, {read:false}).pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('buildrt', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.rt')
    .pipe(rt({modules: 'es6'}))
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(testbuild_dir));
});

gulp.task('buildjs', ['buildrt'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015','react']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(testbuild_dir));
});

gulp.task('testbuild', ['buildjs']);
```

package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base /build --inline --devtool source-map --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "test": "npm run testbuild && npm run testartifacts && npm run testclean",
    "testbuild": "gulp testbuild",
    "testartifacts": "mocha --recursive ./testbuild/js/test",
    "testclean": "gulp clean"
  },
```

Now I can just run `npm run test` and everything works!